# Wamp x64 won't work with php 5.6.16

Tags: php, wamp, php-7, php-5.6, wamp64

I have installed WAMP 3, the x64 bits version that comes with both PHP 7 and PHP 5.6.16.

Thing is, it only works with version 7, but not with version 5.6.16.

If I'm on version 7 I can open localhost just fine, if I switch to version 5.6, it says "This site can’t be reached".
Apache error log:

```
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:42.721292 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00428: Parent: child process 8788 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:42.859839 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:42.936418 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:42.936418 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Oct 11 2015 11:49:07
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:42.936418 2016] [core:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.17\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.17'
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:43.007482 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5336
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:43.647394 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 5336:tid 420] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:43.728167 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5336:tid 420] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:45.162617 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00428: Parent: child process 5336 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:45.368338 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:45.436406 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:45.436406 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Oct 11 2015 11:49:07
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:45.436406 2016] [core:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.17\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.17'
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:45.534501 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8776:tid 652] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7404
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:46.217823 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7404:tid 156] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jul 08 18:59:46.276887 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7404:tid 156] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

First:
Check the apache logs, or run httpd.exe manually and see error response.

Comment: Try run apache manually. in apache 2.4 dir bin/httpd.exe, maybe you get some detailed errors. If it run without errors, then press ctrl+c and exit.

Another little trick for php: go to the your php 5.6 folder and run this command:
php.exe -c php.ini -m
(if your php.ini located in different folder, change it in my command)
this command list your loaded php modules. Maybe some module drop error.